# very important text messages microsoft lumia 535

Tags: sms, backup, lumia-535

I had to do a factory reset on my Lumia 535.

I dont think I backed anything up as I had no contact and backup app.

If my text messages were saved to the cloud etc where would they be or what other places could they have been saved to?

is there also any type of app or method of getting my sms back after a factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the settings for text messages, you should be able to add your Microsoft account to it. If I remember correctly, once you have the correct Microsoft account set up here, the text messages and call history should start downloading slowly in the background.